# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' userRole was null

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am getting this error when I tried to make a put request in my react app. This code snippet is part of my web API.

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
            public Users Get(int id)
            {
                var user = _context.Users.Find(id);
                UserRole userRole = _context.UserRole.FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserId == id);
                user.RoleID = userRole.RoleId;
                return user;
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UserRole userRole = _context.UserRole.FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserId == id);
//here check if userRole is not null:
if (userRole != null)
{
    user.RoleID = userRole.RoleId;
}
```